# BIOS not recognizing USB Boot

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I wanted to install [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net) on a really old computer, so the way I did this was by taking help from this [article](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-lubuntu-linux-distribution-pc-bootable-usb-drive.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20install%20Lubuntu%20Linux%20OS%20on%20PC,and%20boot%20from%20it.%20...%20More%20items...%20) where it showed me how to make a bootable usb to install Lubuntu. But it seems my computer isn't booting up using the USB.

I then tried to change the boot device priority but it isn't recognizing my USB device, even though I made it bootable exactly according to the article. I also tried pressing F12 in my old computer but it just gave me a screen with this Intel PXD thing, I thought of uodating my BIOS but not sure how and if I should do that.

*SPECS: 
Processor: Intel Pentium(R) ES5200 Dual Core @ 2.50Ghz
Brand: Compaq w185q
BIOS Revision: 5.24
Core Version: 6.0
*

NOTE: While booting it showed me this text "Using default BIOS configuration as BIOS Update or System Error", also the computer's OS was Windows but I think it is broke as Windows Boot Manager says "Windows failed to Boot Up a recent hardware or software change might be the reason for this. Please insert your installation disc" and so I thought that it was a problem of the os but now I think that I need to get a  new motherboard and a processor. What is your opinion, and please help me out of this quandry

Comment: this REALLY isnt the right place

Comment: For starters, I'd suggest starting with a Lubuntu grabbed from either Ubuntu, or Lubuntu (https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) as you list a non-Lubuntu (non-Ubuntu) site.  If you don't know how to evaluate a google search, be careful. google offers 3 sites for download of Lubuntu, but only 1 is related to Ubuntu/Lubuntu and thus legitimate.  I'd suggest using ubuntu.com or https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours which will send to you official *flavor* web sites.

Comment: You haven't provided any release details, but I'll start by providing the manual page for Installation (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html)   Lubuntu currently has 3 installers supported for download & use, you've given no clues as to which you've tried to use (and actually mention a non-Lubuntu site!) so I won't try and evaluate your messages.

Comment: Your CPU (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37212/intel-pentium-processor-e5200-2m-cache-2-50-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html) was introduced the same Q3'08 as my own cpu that I'm using to write this comment on (a 2009 dell desktop) and I'm running Lubuntu *hirsute* (what will be 21.04 on release). Did you verify your ISO? and write to install media?  (this varies on release, which you haven't provided..)  but I'd start with a download/ISO from a Ubuntu/Lubuntu site, not a *fan* or unaffiliated site.

Comment: My old systems booted a USB installer from Hard drive sub-menu. In beginning I was trying to boot from various USB entries like USB-HDD, USB-floppy, USB-CD etc. None of the USB entries worked, but a USB installer is seen as a hard drive.

Comment: Based on your notes section: Look up your motherboard. You can probably reset the BIOS by using a jumper. Then, instead of using USB (some older PCs don't boot to USB very well) try a DVD. If you don't have a jumper anywhere, you can make one or there may be one in-use on the back of your optical drive.

Comment: This page tries to list every reason that a bootable USB does not boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot.